# How do I limit the number of items found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a script of tabs in the vastness and redistribution to fit my needs. But I ran into the fact that I have nested tabs. Because of this, when you click on the parent tab, the children are also closed. I decided to go by calculating the number of tabs and displaying only these elements. in the variable length I find the number, but I do not know how to limit the number of tabs to the length length. Help with advice, or advise me how to sort out the situation with nested tabs

```js
function makeTabs() {
  // don't work here. displays the first tab
  var arr = $(".tab-content");
  $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value)
    $(value).children().hide(); 
    $(value).siblings('.tabs-title').children().first().attr("id", "current"); 
    $(value).children().first().fadeIn(); 
  })
}


$('.tabs-title a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let length = $(this).closest('.tabs-title').children().length,
    tab = $(this).closest('.tabs-title').siblings('.tab-content').find('.tab');
  tab.hide();
  $(this).closest('.tabs-title').children('li').attr("id", ""); //Сброс ID
  $(this).parent().attr("id", "current");
  $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
      .tabs-title {
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .tabs-title li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
    }

    .tabs-title a {
      box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      border-top-right-radius: 15px;
      position: relative;
      background: #ddd;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);
      padding: .7em 1.5em;
      float: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);

      /*box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);*/
    }

    .tabs-title a:hover,
    .tabs-title a:hover::after,
    .tabs-title a:focus,
    .tabs-title a:focus::after {
      background: #fff;
    }

    .tabs-title a:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }


    .tabs-title #current a,
    .tabs-title #current a::after {
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .tab-content {
      padding-top: 30px;
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div>
  <ul class="tabs-title">
    <li><a href="javascript:" title="tab1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" title="tab2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:" title="tab3">three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
      some code
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
      some code
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
      <div>
        <ul class="tabs-title">
          <li><a href="javascript:" title="child_tab1">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:" title="child_tab2">two</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:" title="child_tab3">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:" title="child_tab4">four</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:" title="child_tab5">five</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="child_tab1" class="tab">some code</div>
          <div id="child_tab2" class="tab">some code</div>
          <div id="child_tab3" class="tab">some code</div>
          <div id="child_tab4" class="tab">some code</div>
          <div id="child_tab5" class="tab">some code</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add CSS to make it a [mcve]